# How to draw a rectangle perpendicular to a vector in OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, glut

I'm trying to draw a rectangle perpendicular to vector `v`:

```
glPushMatrix()
glTranslatef(v[0], v[1], v[2])
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
glVertex3f( -h, -h, 0)
glVertex3f( h, -h, 0)
glVertex3f( h, h, 0)
glVertex3f( -h, h, 0)
glEnd()
```

The resulting rectangle sits at the end of vector (I need this), how do I make it perpendicular to this vector?

Comment: Yes, it is what i mean.

Comment: yes (too short comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the vector `v` is a in view space, then the x axis points to the left, the y axis points up and z axis points out of the viewport.

Calculate the longitude and latitude - see [Geographic coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system):

```py
import math
```

```py
lenXY = math.sqrt(v[0]*v[0] + v[2]*v[2])
lon   = math.atan2(v[0], v[2])
lat   = math.atan2(v[1], -lenXY)
```

Do a rotation around the x and y axis:

```py
glPushMatrix()
glTranslatef(v[0], v[1], v[2])
glRotatef(math.degrees(lon), 0, 1, 0)
glRotatef(math.degrees(lat), 1, 0, 0)

# [...]

glPopMatrix()
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much!